# Adding a character in auto complete textview is taking to google search screen android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, google-search, android-keypad

I have a AutoCompleteTextview when I enter a character then sometimes it leads to Google search screen of android. I dont know y this is so.

Layout Declaration for AutoCompleteTextview is:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        style="@style/AutoSuggestList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bar_search"
        android:maxLength="1024" 
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="@string/hint_In_searchBar"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
         >

    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

There is also a search Icon over this view at right corner.
But only typing a character itself is leading to Google search.
Example image : [image: google search example image]
<sub>(source: [fonearena.com](http://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Google-Search-for-Android.jpg))</sub>

Device in which I found this issue: Samsung galaxy S, O.S. version : 2.3.4

Please any suggestions for the same.?

Comment: still need the solution for the same.